# Variable has null value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have button and when I click on it, I get an `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` on the following line: `user.isBaned = true;`
The username field which come from button has value. But user doesn't have value. I don't have any idea why?

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Ban(string username)
{ 
    var user = db.Users.Find(username);
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        user.isBaned = true;  
        //db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Redirect("/Admin/Index");
     }

     return Redirect("/Admin/Index");
}
```

View:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Ban" , "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
   <input type="hidden" value="@item.UserName" name="username" />
   <input type="submit" id="username" value="Ban" class="btn-default" />
}
```

Comment: show the code for button click, Is it Html.ActionLink helper?

Comment: No, the actual problem might be that there is no user returned and the user is still null.

Comment: No the username variable has value.

Comment: @DimitarGanichev, they're two different things. Username is a parameter whereas the User is an object that you're finding inside the system. User depends on the Username, but Username doesn't always seem to make sure that there will be a User. Please see my answer to this question.

Comment: I suggest instead of username parameter use public ActionResult Ban(FormCollection collection) as a parameter and take value for the user Name by collection["username"] then debug check any value coming also most importantly check null for user(user != null) because that user not available in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem in your code is that the method to find a user, is returning a null (because the user might not be found).

Just to make sure that this error doesn't get thrown again, you can wrap the code block in a simple if else block. Something like this,

```
if(user != null) {
    // if the user is not null
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        user.isBaned = true;  
        //db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Redirect("/Admin/Index");
    }
}
```

Also, as you're saying, username is having a value. They are two different things, username is a string being passed to the function, where as user is the user that will be found in the system. Having a valid username, doesn't always mean that the user will be valid too. I would like to recommend that you go and check the method value that is returned by the `User.Find(string);` method. It will give you the answer.